# Incorrect Login Goes to 404 instead of LogIn Page

Tags: joomla, authentication, http-status-code-404

I am trying to set up a login portion for my site - and the login is working fine. However, if the login is incorrect, it goes to a 404 page instead of a login page. How can I fix this?

Comment: Step one: Give us some idea what your code looks like.

Comment: Are you using Joomla's built-in login menu item, a module, or something custom?

Comment: Which module are you using for login form?

Comment: @isherwood if it were modified in any way I'd tell you. But everything is standard. Except maybe the custom 404 fix I put in the error.php. But changing that didn't help:

`defined('_JEXEC') or die;
if (($this->error->getCode()) == '404') {
header('Location: /errorpage');
exit;}`

Comment: @isherwood I am using Login Form (the standard Joomla module for login.)

Comment: Do all your other menu items work properly? Maybe an .htaccess issue?

Comment: @isherwood Thanks for the help - the correct solution is listed below. It's just a reconfiguring of the access rights in menu/item/category + reroute via the error.php file.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most joomla login modules have parameters for redirecting users to a menu or a url after successful or unsuccessful login. I guess yours is redirecting users to an upublished menu or item or a broken link.

If you are using Joomla's native Login module or something like `mod_k2_user`, There should be a parameter called `Login Redirection Page` which you can point it to a published menu item.

Go to your administrator area, module manager and find your login module an take a look at it's parameters.

Comment: Thanks. But the Login Redirection should be a login-only page, no? here are the parameters: http://i.imgur.com/QU9bOeP.png

Comment: Login redirection page can be set to `public`, `registered` or `special` menu. Change it and point it to another menu and see what happens.

Comment: Your correct answer was in the comment so I edited your initial answer to include the correct answer. Thanks!!!